# Sqoop Process S3/CSV to S3/Parquet

Tags: hive, sqoop, parquet

Is Sqoop able to target a directory or CSV file stored in S3 and then import to another S3 directory in Parquet?   Have been testing and researching a bit but nothing. Any assistance would be appreciated.